# VB.NET :For each loops with Resultset from LINQ 2 SQL

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, foreach

The below code will fill User Records in "users".

```
    Dim users= From p In oDbUser.USERs Where p.STATE= "MI" And p.STATUS = 1
```

Can anyone tell me how can i use a foreaach loop in the result and take each indidual row items  ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx#linqtosql_topic1

Answer (score 2):

I think you also need a **Select** clause in that linq query.

And that is the most relevant part, assuming a simple `Select p` you can do

```
For Each user In users 

Next user
```

(you may want to check the VB syntax)

Comment: @Geoffrey, Thanks, I will edit. I did warn about my VB skills.